# how to fix mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain error in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an email through a html contact using php. I've done all the necessary php.ini settings and I'm still gettting this error.....=>mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.5.0 Invalid EHLO/HELO domain. in C:\xampp\htdocs\send_form_email.php on line 10

```
<?php $username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$formcontent="From: $username \n Message $description";
$recipient = "ladipupo6@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail('ladipupo6@gmail.com', $subject, $formcontent, $headers = "From: 
ladipupo6@gmail.com");
echo "Thank You!";
 ?>
```

php.ini settings

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP= smtp.mailtrap.io
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from

sendmail_from = ladipupo6@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you hostname settings in the php.ini file.

> ; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
>   ; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

Check the php docs[here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php) for more info